# Apache Beam field-partition

Tags: python, apache-beam, partition, dataflow

I would like to partition a PCollection in Apache Beam using Python by a specific field.

I have found the following code in the Python SDK documentation which partitions the PCollection in

```
students = ...
def partition_fn(student, num_partitions):
  return int(get_percentile(student) * num_partitions / 100)

by_decile = students | beam.Partition(partition_fn, 10)
```

But this is not what I want to do. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

"partition" is not the right transform you need.

You need to use [GroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms)?

Please note that in order to properly work, you must ensure the element to be process has to be a pair. In such a pair, the firs element is always considered the key to be used for the GroupByKey transform.

No further parameters you need.

In my case I had tuples like

```
(key, < list of dictionaries >)
```